# Free SVN and Bug Tracking systems for Closed-source project

Tags: svn, hosting, bug-tracking

I'm working on a project, and we're gonna need some better tools as it's hard sharing over IRC or email. We have a blog and forum, for public use. The bugs go through the forum first, then we approve them. Once they are approved, it goes in the bug tracker, where we can post patches. Also, SVN is used for easy file sharing for the app, like new resources. I jsut want both of these, only bugs and SN. Know of any for my use?

Comment: Is this bait for an ad ?

Comment: Closed-source bug tracker? I meant bug tracker for a closed-source project. Wording confuses everyone near me. ;)

Comment: No, it's not ad bait. We haven't even got the site finished yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trac and SVN can be used by a project of any type; you don't need to be open source to use them.

-- Edit

It appears the OP is looking for a free source-code host, that allows private projects (for example assembla.com is free, but your project must be public, not private, unless you pay).

[xp-dev.com](http://www.xp-dev.com/) is the answer.

Comment: Well I'm trying to find affordable hosting for them, and making sure that repository is private.

Comment: OH! I understand now; you want a hosted service. Check out: http://www.xp-dev.com/, your project can be private.

Comment: i'd strongly recommend also taking a look at unfuddle.com which i mention in my answer. Its a great service which does git and svn and has a good bug tracking system with a free package

Answer (score 1):

If by "we" you only mean 2 developers (plus possibly community users), I would strongly recommend you have a look at [Fog Bugz](http://www.fogbugz.com).  I think it's also free for larger, open-source projects.

I have been using it for a while and really like it.  It's free for 2 or fewer users (plus unlimited community users).

It also happens to be by the same folks that bring you StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

i'd recommend [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) or [codebasehq](http://www.codebasehq.com/) both of which have free plans